# Não insere linhas no DatagridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Eu faço uma select no meu banco e ele traz os valores no datagrid. Porém quando vou tentar adicionar/deletar linhas, dá erro:

> Não é possível adicionar linhas programaticamente à coleção de linhas de DataGridView quando o controle é associado a dados."

Código do Select:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
string comando = "SELECT * FROM item_orcamento where id_orcamento = '"+ Convert.ToInt32(txtidos.Text) + "' and tipo_item='Produto' order by id_orcamento";
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(comando, stringCon);
MySqlCommandBuilder cmdb = new MySqlCommandBuilder(da);
da.Fill(ds, "item_orcamento");
dataGridProdutos.DataSource = ds.Tables["item_orcamento"];
da.Dispose();
```

Código do botão Inserir:

```
private void addDataServicos(string codServico, string nomeServico, string qtdServico, string valorServico, string valorTotalServico)
{
    String[] row = { codServico, nomeServico, qtdServico, valorServico, valorTotalServico };
    dataGridServicos.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

### Como posso inserir novas linhas?

```
    private void CriarRow(DataTable source)
    {
        string valor = txtprecoServico.Text;
        valor = valor.Replace("R$", "");
        int qtd = 0;
        qtd = Convert.ToInt32(txtquantidades.Text);
        double soma = Convert.ToDouble(valor);
        double valorTotalServico = qtd * soma;
        var row = source.NewRow();
        row[0] = 0;
        row[1] = txtcodServico.Text;
        row[2] = 0;//2-tipo_item,
        row[3] = txtnomeServico.Text;
        row[4] = txtquantidades.Text; 
        row[5] = (valor);//5-valor_item,
        row[6] = valorTotalServico.ToString();
        row[7] = txtidos.Text;
        source.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

Comment: Você está usando duas técnicas para preenchimento, acredito ser isso, ou é uma ou é outra! talvez uma estrutura melhor de Lista seria melhor opção

Comment: recomendo utilizar BindingList para trabalhar no datagridview, será muito mais fácil

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa adicionar a linha ao objeto que faz o *binding* dos dados e não direto ao `DataGridView`.

No seu caso, é preciso adicionar as linhas ao `DataTable`

Algo como

```
private void CriarRow(DataTable source)
{
    var row = source.NewRow();
    row[0] = "Alguma coisa";
    row[1] = "E assim por diante";
    source.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Uso

```
var dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridProdutos.DataSource;
CriarRow(dataTable);
```

Comment: Oi, eu tentei adequar aqui, mas não acontece nada:

Comment: @Jessf E não dá erro?

Comment: Não, ele só add uma linha vazia.

Comment: Então não quer dizer que nada acontece, quer dizer que está fazendo o que é esperado. Só que deve estar faltando algo.

Comment: @Jessf Como está o seu código que adiciona a linha?

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta.

Comment: Quando eu tento alterar um cadastro já existente, ele não faz nada, mas quando tento inserir um novo cadastro e inserir o item no datagrid ele me dá esse erro: "Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: Então o problema não absolutamente nada a ver com a minha solução. Vamos por partes, certo? Primeira coisa, se você remover todo o código do seu método e fazer apenas `var row = source.NewRow(); source.Rows.Add(row);`. Funciona numa boa?

Comment: Ele dá esse erro: "Additional information: Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."

Comment: Dentro do método, o valor de `source` está como `null`?

Comment: Ahh rapaz! Aí é que tá! var dataTable = (DataTable)dataGridServicos.DataSource;
            CriarRow(dataTable);, ele tá assim.

Comment: E o que isso quer dizer?

Comment: ele define o datagrid como source

Comment: @Jessf Não, isso captura o DataSource do DataGrid. Você ainda não respondeu a minha outra pergunta. `souce` está como `null` dentro do método?

Comment: Tô confusa. Ele não passa nenhum valor para o source.

Comment: @Jessf Ele quem? De quem você tá falando?

Comment: O método. Ele só passa essas duas linhas que eu coloquei ali em cima.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso o erro ocorreu, porque defini na forma gráfica a data source ao remover, resolvi o erro .

[image: Erro]

Colocando a data source como none resolvi o problema

```
foreach (var animal in listaAnimais)
            {
                DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                dataGridAnimal.Rows.Add(row);

                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[0].Value = animal.ID;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[1].Value = animal.Nome;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[2].Value = animal.Especie;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[3].Value = animal.Raca;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[4].Value = animal.Genero;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[5].Value = animal.Peso;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[6].Value = animal.Esterilizacao;
                dataGridAnimal.Rows[linha].Cells[7].Value = animal.DataNascimento;
                linha++;
            }
```